# Create a CSV download using silverlight 4 and c#

Tags: silverlight, csv, download, content-type

I'm struggling to find an example or code to be able to create CSV or text file in silverlight as a downloadable link.

I've done this in ASP.net but can't figure out a way using Silverlight.  Am I spinning my wheels? Or should I just create an ASP page? Is there a way of doing this in c#?

I'd like to do this the right way and not some hack job and will appreciate any feedback and advice.

In ASP I would of used:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""EPIC0B00.CSV"""
Response.write....
```

Comment: In the situations like this I use an ashx-handler and a link from a silverlight application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve with very similar code as above, just including required references so there is no assumptions made, plus this is an actual working example.

```
using System;  
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;  
using System.Windows.Controls;
....

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = ExportData(); // This is where the data is built
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()
        {
        DefaultExt = "csv",
        Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*",
        FilterIndex = 1
        };
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (Stream stream = sfd.OpenFile())
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) {
                writer.Write(data);  //Write the data :)
                writer.Close();
                }
                stream.Close();
             }
        }
    }

    private string ExportData()
    {
       return "!this is the exported text";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is a client side technology.  You can't point a browser at it and "download" a CSV or anything else from it.

Instead you use the `SaveFileDialog` class.  Here is a chunk of code based on the MSDN docs for it:-

```
SaveFileDialog csvDialog;
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    csvDialog= new SaveFileDialog();
    csvDialog.Filter = "CSV Files| *.csv";
    csvDialog.DefaultExt = "csv";
 }

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool? result = csvDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        System.IO.Stream fileStream = csvDialog.OpenFile();
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileStream);

        // Call a method to write your CSV content to the sw here

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```